# HP-UX: regular expression repetition does not work?

Tags: regex, sed, hp-ux

I want to pick up those rows whose 4th filed is not empty.
But the following RE did not work:

```
^\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,][^,]*,.*$
```

Then I tried to print the captured groups, the result confused me.
It seems that the repetition does not work.
Would anyone explain it, please.

Details(see line 4~6):

```
$ cat tmp
1AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
2AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
3AAA,BBB,,DDD,EEE,FFF
4AAA,BBB,CCC,,EEE,FFF
5AAA,BBB,CCC,,EEE,FFF
6AAA,BBB,CCC,,EEE,FFF
7AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
8AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
9xxxxxxx

$ sed -n "/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\([^,][^,]*\)\(,.*\)$/ {s//\1/;p;}" tmp
1AAA,BBB,CCC,
2AAA,BBB,CCC,
3AAA,BBB,,
4AAA,BBB,
5AAA,BBB,
6AAA,BBB,
7AAA,BBB,CCC,
8AAA,BBB,CCC,
$ uname
HP-UX
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: I want to know why 4~6 lines were printed. {3} should get 3 fileds...but those lines have only two filed.

Comment: I don't know why you used a complex command for this simple task.

Comment: Can you explain the regex please?

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` will print all lines where 4th  field is not empty.

```
awk -F, '$4' file
1AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
2AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
3AAA,BBB,,DDD,EEE,FFF
7AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
8AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
```

It may be simpler to work with `awk` in this case, since it simple to test fields.
Here it just test if `$4` is not empty, and print the line.

Comment: Thanks. But what I want to know is why regex repetition does not work.

Comment: I know, but using regex may not always be the simplest solution, and this `awk` is easy to understand and should work on all system. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below GNU sed command,

```
$ sed -nr '/^[A-Z0-9]+,[A-Z]*,[A-Z]*,[A-Z]+,[A-Z]*,[A-Z]*$/p' file
```

OR

```
$ sed -nr '/^.*,.*,.*,.+,.*,.*$/p' file
1AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
2AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
3AAA,BBB,,DDD,EEE,FFF
7AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
8AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
```

Comment: Yes, the GUN version works fine. Just HP-UX won't work.

Comment: OP does not say that fields needs to be alphanumeric characters, just empty.  So it fails with field `4` = `3345`

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is way simpler to do this with awk, as shown by the slim and perfectly working answer proposed by Jotne.

If you want to investigate what's wrong with your HP-UX sed thing, I would suggest you have a look at [this conversation](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/37583-sed-behavior-hp-ux.html) and try to pass your data not through a file but through the stdin of sed: `cat tmp | sed -n ...` or `sed -n ... < tmp`.

My very first attempt at troubleshooting your issue, though, would be to replace your double quotes by single quotes, as maybe with your double quotes your shell is trying to interpret `$/` or `*`, I don't know what shell you are using...

Comment: Thanks. It's sh and still not working. I noticed they mentioned HPUX version. Mine is 11.11.  May be it's just a bug.  Another similar issue: [grep-regex-question](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/72065-grep-regex-question.html)